# Dynamically injecting instances via CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

In Java EE platform with the CDI there is ability to inject instances of POJO classes.
In very simple way we need use @Inject annotation to inject a default instance of some Interface. We also may use qualifiers to inject concrete class to our field.
But these solutions are rather static.

I need some more dynamical model of injecting stuff.

Let me introduce my problem:
Let's say that we have interface Animal and three classes that implement that interface: Ant, Dog, Elephant.
I would like to dynamically inject instance of one of these three classes, and it depends on some variable like string (animal name).
In Java SE I'd do it like below:

```
Map<String, Animal> animalMap = new HashMap<>();
animalMap.put("ant", new Ant());
animalMap.put("dog", new Dog());
animalMap.put("elephant", new Elephant());
...
String animalName = ...;
Animal animal = animalMap.get(animalMap);
animal.doSomething();
```

So I need something like:

```
class AnimalManager {
   @Inject // ?
   private Animal animal; // ?

   public void run(String animalName) {
      // based on animalName get new instance of animal and run doSomething()
      ...
      animal.doSomething(); // if animalName is "ant" call the doSomething on Ant class
   }
}
```

In all classes that implement Animal interface I need use variables with @EJB annotations.

What the best and most proper way to do it in Java EE?

EDIT:
OK based on response from Svetlin Zarev and hwellmann (thanks!) I have created this:

On the beginning we will create Animal model:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface AnimalModel {

   Type value();

   enum Type { ANT, DOG, ELEPHANT }

}
```

Let's create the Animal:

```
public interface Animal {
   public void eat(Object food);
}
```

Next, concrete classes:

```
@AnimalModel(AnimalModel.Type.ANT)
public class Ant implements Animal {

   @Override   
   public void eat(Object food) {
      ...
   }

}

@AnimalModel(AnimalModel.Type.DOG)
public class Dog implements Animal {

   @Override   
   public void eat(Object food) {
      ...
   }

}

@AnimalModel(AnimalModel.Type.ELEPHANT)
public class Elephant implements Animal {

   @Override   
   public void eat(Object food) {
      ...
   }

}
```

Next, AnimalLiteral:

```
public class AnimalLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<AnimalModel> implements AnimalModel {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private Type type;
   public AnimalLiteral(Type type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   public Type value() {
      return type;
   }
}
```

The main component is the Animal factory:

```
@Dependent
public class AnimalFactory {

   @Inject
   @Any
   private Instance<Animal> animals;

   private static Map<String, AnimalModel.Type> animalMap;

   public AnimalFactory() {
       animalMap = new HashMap<>();
       animalMap.put("ant", AnimalModel.Type.ANT);
       animalMap.put("dog", AnimalModel.Type.DOG);
       animalMap.put("elephant", AnimalModel.Type.ELEPHANT);
   }

   public Animal getAnimal(String animalName) {
      AnimalModel.Type type = animalMap.get(animalName);
      AnimalLiteral literal = new AnimalLiteral(type);
      Instance<Animal> animalInstance = animals.select(literal);
      return animalInstance.get();
   }
}
```

And client:

```
public class Client {

   @Inject
   private AnimalFactory animalFactory;

   public void run(String animalName) {
      Animal animal = animalFactory.getAnimal(animalName);
      animal.eat("some food...");
   }

}
```

I don't know that putting the map animalMap in that place is right...?

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection.

Answer (score 9):

Using `Instance<T>` in combination with qualifiers is the standard way in CDI to perform dynamic injection.

You need a qualifier with a binding argument, e.g. `@Species("ant")` to distinguish your implementation classes.

```
public class AnimalSelector {

    @Inject
    @Any 
    private Instance<Animal> animals;

    public Animal selectAnimalBySpecies(String speciesName) {
        SpeciesLiteral qualifier = new SpeciesLiteral(speciesName);
        return animals.select(qualifier).get();
    }
}

public class SpeciesLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Species> implements Species {

    private String name;

    public SpeciesLiteral(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Species {

    String value() default "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to achieve such dynamic injection with CDI, simply because the dependencies are injected when the container instantiates the managed bean. In other words, when you call `run()` on your `AnimalManager`, the `Animal` dependency, would have already been injected.

What you can do is to inject `AnimalFactory` and on each call just do lets say `AnimalFactory.createAnimal(animal);` or use something like your map approach.

Comment: How is this not just downvoting my answer and restating it?

Comment: you are talking about HK2, CDI alternatives, SOAP, Spring, design, and other mambo jambo , but you did not explain why plain CDI would not work and did not mention a concrete mechanism of achieving the desired goal. Just compare my brief, conscious and clear answer which consist of 1 (one) sentence with your "novel".

Comment: This is incorrect. CDI looks up the instance when you attempt to use it. When you just called `AnimalManager#run` there may exist no `Animal` instances whatsoever. It's when you call `animal.doSomething` - that's when the `Animal` instance is looked up or created. `AnimalManager#animal` is not a direct reference, it's a Contextual Proxy.

Comment: IIRC `@Dependent` is an exception though, because its context basically is the injection point. It probably is injected right into the field, maybe with a wrapper if there are Inteceptors or something like that.